# Test Class Input

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I have a Batch class:

```
global class updateCusotmerMasterData implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful,Database.AllowsCallouts
{
    public updateCusotmerMasterData(){}
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {   
        return Database.getQueryLocator([Select id,iCustomer__c  from account where ID NOT IN (Select Account__c from DetailSet__c)]);
        //return Database.getQueryLocator([select id,iCustomer__c from Account where Icustomer__c ='00BE01 Approval UAT10']);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> Acc)
    {
        list<String> Icustomer = new list<string>();
        for(account Acc1 : Acc)
        {
            Icustomer.add(Acc1.iCustomer__c);
        }
        HTTPSclass.HTTPSclass1(Icustomer);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    }
}
```

I have a test Class:

I have created the Http Mock request to generate mock response class:

```
@isTest

public class SingleRequestMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

        protected Integer code;

        protected String status;

        protected String bodyAsString;

        protected Blob bodyAsBlob;

        protected Map<String, String> responseHeaders;



        public SingleRequestMock(Integer code, String status, String body,

                                         Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {

            this.code = code;

            this.status = status;

            this.bodyAsString = body;
            this.bodyAsBlob = null;

            this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;

        }


        public SingleRequestMock(Integer code, String status, Blob body,

                                         Map<String, String> responseHeaders) {

            this.code = code;

            this.status = status;

            this.bodyAsBlob = body;

            this.bodyAsString = null;

            this.responseHeaders = responseHeaders;

        }



        public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

            HttpResponse resp = new HttpResponse();

            resp.setStatusCode(code);

            resp.setStatus(status);

            if (bodyAsBlob != null) {

                resp.setBodyAsBlob(bodyAsBlob);

            } else {

                resp.setBody(bodyAsString);

            }



            if (responseHeaders != null) {

                 for (String key : responseHeaders.keySet()) {

                resp.setHeader(key, responseHeaders.get(key));

                 }

            }

            return resp;

        }

}
```

I have written test class for above batch class:

```
@isTest
public class TestupdateCusotmerMasterData 
{
    static testmethod void test()
    {
        list<Account> TestAcc = new list<Account>();
        for (Integer i=0;i<10;i++) 
        {
            account acc = new account();
            acc.Name='account'+i;
            acc.iCustomer__c = 'aaa'+i;
            acc.PG_JnJCustomerCode__c='aaa'+i;
            acc.PG_AccountGuid__c='aaa'+i;
            TestAcc.add(acc);
        }
        insert TestAcc; 
        Test.startTest();
        updateCusotmerMasterData UpdateCustomer = new updateCusotmerMasterData();

        singleRequestMock fakeResponse = new SingleRequestMock();

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, fakeResponse);

        Database.executeBatch(UpdateCustomer);

        System.assertEquals(/*check for expected results here...*/);
         Test.stopTest();

    }

}
```

It is Showing Error like:

**Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined: [SingleRequestMock].() at line 20 column 42** What is the input should i have to give in the test class Please anyone Guide me for the Answer and also guide me for test class

Comment: Can you try setting the class `SingleRequestMock` to `global` instead of `public`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass parameters as you specified in SingleRequestMock() constructor like this.

```
SingleRequestMock fakeResponse = new SingleRequestMock(
                                                 200,
                                                 'Complete',
                                                 '[{"Name":"sForceTest1"}]', //Sample response from your http request
                                                 null);
```

Refere this for more info.
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html[enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/03/testing-apex-callouts-using-httpcalloutmock.html)